# Is it possible to downgrade project files?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to downgrad migrated projectfile from version 6.0.1 down to version 5.1.15? How much effort would it take it it would be possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the version number in the config element of the project file to "5.1.15", then install4j 5 should be able to open it. As for the changes in the project file format, you can have a look config/transforms/transform5.xsl to see which elements have been affected by changes. You would have to check all those elements in your project since they may have lost some of their configuration.